# Running console app multiple times with different config files

Tags: c#, console-application

I have written a console app (`app.exe`) which has settings in the config file (`app.exe.config`).

I need to run this multiple times with differnet settings in the config file.

The very unelegant solution I use right now is to rename both, `app1.exe`, `app1.exe.config`, etc and then schedule a seperate task for each app so that it runs in the morning.

What I would like to do is have a master config that references the different configs and then have only one `app.exe master.app.exe.config` which then runs `app.exe` as many times as there are references in the master config.

I do not want to do this in code as I would like to explain users how to maintain the config file and thats it...

Example of a setting would be:

```
<!-- datstr ="" => current date, datstr="yyyymmdd" => 
            specific date, datstr ="yyyymmdd,yyyymmdd, 
           etc" => multidate, DONT USE "yyyymmdd","yyyymmdd" -->
<add key="datstr" value=""/>
```

**Is this possible? Is there a better way?**

Comment: When scheduling and task becomes complex It's better to use a service with timer and threads

Comment: What sort of `different settings` in each config file do you mean?

Comment: @Peter: Mostly I set variables. Rundate "" = today, or string[] for historic runs, sourcepath for files, destination paths for output, what type of aggregation algorithm is desired, that sort of thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can understand I believe that you do not have the best architecture to do the job you want to do.

I'd suggest extracting the instance specific configuration from the app.exe.config file and moving it into separate instance specific configuration files.  Then you load the correct configuration file via a command line switch.

Instead of

```
app1.exe (and app1.exe.config)
app2.exe (and app2.exe.config)
app3.exe (and app3.exe.config)
```

You end up with:

```
app.exe (app.exe.config)
instance1.xml
instance2.xml
instance3.xml
```

and run them (for example) by:

```
app.exe -c instance1.xml
app.exe -c instance2.xml
app.exe -c instance3.xml
```

(Note the use of -c and.xml are purely for example purposes only - use what works for you)

This has benefits such as:

1. Scheduling could then be left up to the windows task scheduler.
2. Users can more easily edit and test different config files etc.
3. Users aren't editing your app.config file, so it can be better protected from accidental changes.
4. You only have to give detailed instructions about editing the instance specific files (although I will hate you if you don't document the app.config file ;-) )

Comment: Thanks Peter. Can you elaborate a bit more please? Or do you have a link with more detailed example please? I dont know what instance1.xml need to look like and how you point app.exe to the right instance. Thanks!

Comment: So you mean instance1.xml as argument in task scheduler and then change the code so that it reads settings from the xml as opposed to the config file? That still means I have to schedule a seperate task for each run though!?

Comment: @nik `instance1.xml` is a file you define to look like what you want.  You read manually read its location from the `command line arguments` that you provide to the app.exe program.  Inside your program you read the location of that file, manually read the configuration file and extract the required information.  I used `xml` as an example name as there are a lot of .net functions for working with `xml`.

Comment: Got you (and see above...:) ) but that still means I have to schedule a seperate task for each run, only thing I gain is that I have 1 app and x xml's as opposed to x apps and configs

Comment: @nik Unless you want to write your own scheduler (which is a different sort of problem) then yes, you will need to schedule things somehow.  This solution breaks the task into smaller parts.  As shown you have the tools to more easily get multiple instances up and running.  If you want you can come back later and write your own scheduler over the top of it all - but only if needed

Comment: @nik .. you gain flexibility that can be leveraged in multiple ways

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. I see the benefit for sure. I just had the illusion that I could trigger it all with one schedule in the task manager as opposed to 5 or 6 - thats all. I know at least 1 is required and by the looks of it even more...